# Migration problem with flutter 3.16. Unexpected kernel version 89 (expected 111)

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, migration

I'm currently working on a flutter project in android studio. After updating flutter version to 3.16 I'm having problems with building my application.
I've tried:

1.Downgrading flutter version(and upgrading again).
2.Upgrading dependencies.
3.Deleting .idea directory
4.Running flutter clean
5.Creating new project nad copping code files
6.Upgrading IDE (giraffe now)

The console output after all this steps is:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 in debug mode...
Unhandled exception:
Unexpected Kernel Format Version 89 (expected 111)
#0      BinaryBuilder.readComponent.<anonymous closure> (package:kernel/binary/ast_from_binary.dart:692:9)
#1      Timeline.timeSync (dart:developer/timeline.dart:173:22)
#2      BinaryBuilder.readComponent (package:kernel/binary/ast_from_binary.dart:679:21)
#3      _InitializationFromSdkSummary._prepareSummary (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:2467:12)
#4      _InitializationFromUri.initialize (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:2541:23)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      IncrementalCompiler._ensurePlatformAndInitialize (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:1421:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:308:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      CompilerContext.clear (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:139:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      IncrementalCompiler.compile (package:vm/incremental_compiler.dart:75:50)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:610:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     listenAndCompile.<anonymous closure> (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:1323:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. run `flutter clean`
2. delete the corrupted `flutter/bin/cache` directory on disk
3. run `flutter`
4. run `flutter pub get`